# convert Selected date to String

Tags: android

I wanted to convert Selected Date into String So that I can use it in my Main2Activity.java  with the help of EXTRA_TEXT.

Thanks in Advance for helping.

```
 cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,int month, int day) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried something? what problem did you faced?

Comment: am unable to convert it.. I tried searching on web but can't get a perfect result..

Comment: but what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to change a date to a string:

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String result = formatter.format(date.getTime());
```

Comment: You're very welcome!  Don't forget to accept the answer please! :)

Comment: and another issue, when ever am scrolling calendar view, then another activity (Main2Activity) is poping up for the above code which i mentioned... Is there any Solution for that? I will be glad if you could help me in it..